# c++ function returns two different types

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I'm creating a queue template class using C++.

The queue class has multiple function members. One of the functions is called front() to retrieve the first value of queue. Basically, the front() function will first check if the queue is empty or not (using another bool function is_empty()).

If it is empty, the function will throw error message and return 1 to indicate there is an error. If the queue is not empty, it will return the first value, whose type is same as that of data in queue. As you can see, there are two different types of return values. How can I specify those two types together when define the function?

Sample code is below. The return type is T. But the function also returns 1. Is this acceptable in C++? If not, how to modify it? Thanks in advance!

```
template <class T>
T MyQueue<T>::front() {
    if (! is_empty()) {
        return my_queue[0];
    }
    else {
        cout << "queue is empty!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this not a good place to use exceptions?

Comment: You could use `std::variant`. Also don't spam version flags. If you use C++17 then don't put C++11 in. Also you might want to move to C++ style error handling (i.e. exceptions). Also if you want to do this instead, then you might also just create a `struct` that has a boolean flag to indicate an error, and the returned object (this would be only possible/convenient if pointer return, or default constructable return is used). With pointers you can always just return `nullptr` though...

Comment: I would suggest 2 things
1) instead of `return 1`, probably a better idea if you do `throw "Queue is empty!`. 
2) if you have declared `front` variable in your class (you should) then`return my_queue[front]`

Comment: For the sake of building intuition: what would the code that called this function (as written) look like if `T` were, say, `std::string`?

Comment: There is another option: leaving it undefined when the container is empty, like what the standard library does, thus it is the caller's responsibility to ensure the container is not empty. Of course, this approach sacrifices safety in exchange for efficiency. There is a trade-off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

```
template <class T>
std::optional<T> MyQueue<T>::front() {
    // You should remove the object from the queue here too:
    if (!is_empty()) return my_queue[0];
    return {};
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
    if(auto opt = queue_instance.front(); opt) {
        auto value = std::move(opt).value();
        std::cout << "got :" << value << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "no value right now\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. Just a quick question: why value() method is used in std::move(opt).value()? I think std::move(opt) is exactly my_queue[0] already?

Comment: @zurich_ruby The move is nice if you want to move "expensive" objects out of the `optional`. It's not needed though. You could just use `opt.value()` directly. Note that the `value()` member function has two overloads and by using `std::move` I choose the one to move the object out of the `optional`

Comment: Thanks. Just found this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value

Comment: @zurich_ruby Yeah, that's the good site (the same I linked to in the answer). I like that a lot.

Comment: `std::optional` is used to **hold** an object. It is more proper for `front` to return a "view" rather than an "object",  so a plain pointer seems more proper than `std::optional`.

Comment: @xskxzr If `front()` is supposed to **not** extract the first element I would make it return a reference instead and let it be UB if it's called when the queue is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest returning `T*` as a pointer. If the queue is empty, then return null.

```
template <class T>
T* MyQueue<T>::front() {
    return is_empty() ? nullptr : &my_queue[0];
}

if (auto obj = queue.front()) {
    obj->...
}
```